# Sun protection clothing

Tags: clothes, sun-protection

I would like to see if there is clothing that can provide sun protection while
minimizing sweating and/or allow air flow.

Would also like to do the same with my bike helmet without compromising safety.

Ideas?

Comment: Essentially any clothing will provide some sun protection, simply because light can only pass through gaps between the fibres (which is why clothing isn't transparent).

Comment: Cotton is of a low protection value. UPF ranges from 3 (wet) to 5 (dry). Artificial fibres are usually > 50 UPF. I have had stripy head after long days on the bike in summer but have no hair. Do use sunscreen under your helmet but watch out for sweat/sunscreen  drip into your eyes which can be painful.

Comment: You make a good point. I forgot about the ventilation holes. I have some fabric on the inside of my helmet but it only covers about 1/4 of my head. I will use a thicker soft fabric and line the whole inside. @Warren Burton

Comment: If its hot enough, you're going to sweat.  So the answer becomes more how to deal with sweat rather than prevention.

Answer (score 5):

Many items of quality cycling clothing from reputable brands with high SPF are available. Under-helmet caps with the sun protection are available as well.

Since this site doesn't do product recommendations you'll need to browse producer and retailer sites.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the Wikipedia page for "[Sun Protective Clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_protective_clothing)":

> A number of fabrics and textiles in common use today **need no further UV-blocking enhancement** based on their inherent fiber structure, density of weave, and dye components, especially darker colors and indigo dyes. Good examples of these fabrics contain full percentages or blends of heavy-weight natural fibers like cotton, linen and hemp or **light-weight synthetics such as polyester, nylon, spandex** and polypropylene.

(Emphasis mine.)

What that means is that most common cycling gear like jerseys (typically polyester), shorts (nylon + spandex), arm- and leg-warmers (ditto) is already basically UV-blocking.  The exception would obviously be for fabric made as an open weave or mesh for breathability.  (I once got an interesting pointillist sunburn through the mesh panels of a non-cycling workout top.)

Anecdotally, I can say that in >20 years of cycling, including some long 12-hour days in the sun, I've never once gotten a burn through solid-fabric cycling gear.  (The knitted backs of certain cycling gloves, on the other hand...)

So there is **no need to replace existing cycling gear** with new just to get "UPF 50+" fabrics.  You're just looking to cover up skin that you would previously have exposed to the sun.

In my case that meant shopping for a cap to wear under my helmet and lightweight arm and leg protection.  I also had a strong preference for a white colour, since if it's cool enough to wear black it's probably also cool enough to wear my arm-warmers.  (Similarly leg-warmers or tights.)

Fortunately my LBS had several styles in stock to compare.  The black UPF 50+ arm protection were virtually indistinguishable from "normal" arm-warmers except for a 20% price premium.  There were 2 comparable (same price-point) white UPF 50+ arm products from different manufacturers; one was *significantly* thicker and heavier than the other.  (It was almost merely a white version of an arm-warmer.)  The lighter ones feel like they have a slightly tighter weave, but seem to have excellent breathability and have worked fine for me in practice.

I would definitely recommend trying to find a place to check any products out in person, rather than buying them sight-unseen online.

Note that you will still want to carry a small amount of sunscreen so you can apply it to places where you're not completely covered up; a problem spot for me seems to be the bones of my wrists where the cycling gloves don't quite match up to the arm protectors.

Comment: I bought a long sleeve polyester shirt for skin protection. I rode about 30 minutes at about 7 mph. My arms did not get warm or very sweaty. I sweated a lot under my helmet. Looking for something to put in the lining that I can take out for washing that will protect my head from the sun going thru the vents in the helmet.

Comment: @fixit7 a buff goes well under a helmet to keep sun off the head.  You can also wet it to keep you cool on very hot days.